# uilabel is chopping text in attributed text of right-to-left languages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am working on a chat app in which I am displaying text in bubbles, some times text is small and some times text is large and I have to calculate text width & height to draw my label, till here all is working well no issues.

Now I have to support url link, email detection etc, for this I have to use attributed text(I am using http://nimbuskit.info). For english language no problem but for languages right-to-left creates issue that label height is not calculating correctly.

I tried lots of things in code and searching on internet but didn't found any solution, so for tracing root cause I created a single view project in Xcode and in its interface builder I created two labels 1st is attributed and another is plain text, please view the screenshot, attributed text is formatted differently from plain text.

xcode interface builder it self is creating this issue.

The width(220) & hight(608) of these label are set by running my actual code please view the code.

```
-(NIAttributedLabel*)lbl
{
    NSString *text = @"وأضاف لافروف نبذل ما في وسعنا لتهيئة الظروف لبدء هذا الحوار في أسرع وقت بدون شروط مسبقة طبقا للاتفاقات المنصوص عليها في بيان جنيف التي يعمل مبعوث جامعتكم والأمم المتحدة الأخضر الإبراهيمي على تحقيقها. وحول الوضع في الشرق الأوسط قال لافروف إن موسكو ليست راضية عن الوضع القائم في المنطقة، نظرا إلى عدد من الأمور التي تثير قلقنا وقلقكم. وأوضح أنه يقصد ظهور بؤر للنزاعات المسلحة في المنطقة، وتنامي ظاهرة التطرف والإرهاب، وانتشار الأسلحة دون حسيب أو رقيب. وحث لافروف الجامعة على أن تؤدي دورا رئيسيا في حل النزاعات الدائرة في العالم العربي بعيدا عن أي تدخل خارجي لا يوافق عليه مجلس الأمن الدولي. وحول النزاع الفلسطيني الإسرائيلي شدد لافروف على ضرورة تكثيف جهود الوسطاء الدوليين والجامعة العربية لإنهائه. وأكد لافروف على أن روسيا تؤيد قرار الجامعة العربية بشأن عقد مؤتمر يتبنى إعلان إقامة منطقة خالية من أسلحة الدمار الشامل في الشرق الأوسط، مشيرا إلى أن روسيا ستعمل على تنفيذ هذا القرار. وكان منتدى التعاون الروسي العربي قد أسس في ديسمبر/كانون الأول من عام 2009. وحُددت مهمته في الارتقاء بمستوى التعاون بين روسيا وأعضاء جامعة الدول العربية. ولم يتمكن المنتدى من عقد أي اجتماع حتى الآن بسبب أحداث العالم العربي التي أعقبت صدور إعلان تأسيسه......";

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];

    NIAttributedLabel* label = [[NIAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    label.text = text;

    label.numberOfLines = 0;

    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    label.attributesForHighlightedLink = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:(id)RGBCOLOR(255, 0, 0).CGColor forKey:(NSString *)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName];

    label.delegate = self;

    label.autoDetectLinks = YES;

    label.linksHaveUnderlines = YES;

    label.font = font;

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    [label sizeToFit];

    [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

    NSMutableAttributedString *aStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:[label attributedText]]; // trying to get width height of attributed text

    CGSize size = [aStr.string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    NSLog(@"SIZE=> %0.f-%0.f | %0.f-%0.f",size.width, size.height, label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);

    return label;
}
```

how to resolve this issue? do width and height of attributed text has to be calculated? 
NSMutableAttributedString do not have sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode ...

Please help.

After 5 hours posting this question I am still looking for solution..I found [this](http://haddadissa.blogspot.com/2010/09/compute-needed-heigh-for-fixed-width-of.html) but this didn't solved the problem completely. Please view the link.

After 6 hours, another issue i forgot to mention `aStr.size.width` or `aStr.size.height` causing app crash giving this error:

> -[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71bc3d0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType lineBreakMode]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71bc3d0'

[image]